# Ubuntu 14.04 is not recognizing Red Hat 6 Enterprise Linux to do Dual Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

My biggest issue is having Ubuntu recognize RHEL as an Operating System.  I initially installed RHEL first and then tried Ubuntu.  When installing Ubuntu, I wouldn't get the statement that says, " we found another Operating System, would you like to have both?" I tried it the other way around (Ubuntu first and then RHEL), but somehow I would end up wiping Ubuntu and get stuck only with RHEL.

My second issue is when I have installed both OS, why does GRUB2 or GRUB 0.97 find both OS? (and yes, I did run update-grub, but no luck).

Can someone kindly assist me?

Answer (score 3):

So, below is what I did:

I used Live Ubuntu and fired up gparted and created two partitions:

```
sda1    ext4    Ubuntu (with boot flag)
sda2    fat32   Red Hat
```

Next, I used the RHEL Boot CD, and it first asked,

> What type of devices will your installation involve?

I choose the first one, “Basic Storage Device”. It then asked

> Which type of installation would you like

I think I clicked on “Create Custom Layout”.  I do remember not choosing, “Use Free Space” nor “Shrink Current System”. Regardless, the option I choose automatically checked off a checkbox at the button: see screenshot below:

[image]
Herein under Hard Drives I choose sda2 and clicked next.  I got this error: see screenshot below:

[image]

I then clicked on sda2 and clicked ‘edit’.  I basically set the mount point to: / and file type ext4: see screenshot below:

[image]

It then asked me if I was sure to write to disk and I hit “yes”.

#### Now, the next part is crucial in making the whole thing work.

- I was then asked about the bootloader.  Since RHEL’s GRUB was 0.97 and was not recognizing Ubuntu after I installed it previously, I choose to **not install a bootloader**.
- After clicking next and finishing up, it asked to reboot and it did not boot RHEL.  It took me to a grub rescue screen.  (its fine).
- I then rebooted the PC and used the 14.04 Live Ubuntu USB.  Ubuntu then asked that it found another Operating System and if I would like to have both.  I choose “yes” and continued the process.

Finally, when I did a reboot GRUB2 appeared and had both OS.